# How may I draw a line, then create a clipping plane from it in three.js? Working example inside

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, geometry

How may I draw a line, and create a clipping plane from it? Almost working example inside.

https://decadent3d.s3.amazonaws.com/data/test.html

Everything is in the page source.

//you need to uncomment the actual problem line//

function newClipping() allows me to draw a line on a plane that always faces the camera,

I get the start and end points (Vector3s) from it and create a new THREE.Line3

Then I use the Line3.GetCenter() to net my 3rd Vector3.

Then using the math I found online in the link below, I get to work.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-equation-of-a-plane-passing-through-3-points/

But it doesn't work.

Anyone much better than this hobbyist right here???

https://www.reddit.com/r/threejs/comments/r6qh38/how_may_i_draw_a_line_and_create_a_clipping_plane/

Comment: `THREE.Plane()` has this [method](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=plane#api/en/math/Plane.setFromCoplanarPoints) to set a plane from three coplanar points. `.getCenter()` of `THREE.Line3()` gives you a point, that lies right in between of line's ends, thus you've got three points on the same line, not sure you can call them coplanar in this case. To build a plane, I would use two points of the line you draw and camera's position.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that worked in the end...

```
//working sample

let myButton = document.getElementById('ClippingButton');

function removeClipping() {
                  
    renderer.clippingPlanes = [];
    myButton.innerText = 'Slice Models';
    myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {drawEnabled = true; newClipping();}, { once: true });

};

function newClipping() {

    myButton.innerText = 'Draw a Line';
    myButton.style.color = '#fccf03';
        
    rackballcontrol.enabled = false;
        
    var hitPlane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(200,200),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ transparent: true, opacity: 0.0 }) );
    hitPlane.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);
    scene.add(hitPlane);
        
    var lineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([ new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3() ]);
    var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
    var newLine = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
    scene.add( newLine );
       
    var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var hitPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
    var isMouseDown = false;

    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
        if (e.button === 0) {
            var x = (e.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
            var y = -(e.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
            rayCaster.setFromCamera({ x, y }, camera);
            var intersections = rayCaster.intersectObject(hitPlane);
        if (intersections && intersections.length) {
            isMouseDown = true;
            hitPoint.copy(intersections[0].point);
            lineGeometry.setFromPoints([ hitPoint, intersections[0].point ]);
        };
        };
    }, { once: true });
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
        if (isMouseDown) {
            var x = (e.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
            var y = -(e.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
            rayCaster.setFromCamera({ x, y }, camera);
            var intersections = rayCaster.intersectObject(hitPlane);
        if (intersections && intersections.length) {
            lineGeometry.setFromPoints([ hitPoint, intersections[0].point ])
        };
        };
    });
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
        for (i = 0; i < meshArray.length; i++) {
            if(meshArray[i].visible === true){
            matArray[i].opacity = 1;
            };
                };
        isMouseDown = false;
        trackballcontrol.enabled = true;

        var lineArray = newLine.geometry.attributes.position.array;
        var vectA = new THREE.Vector3(lineArray[0],lineArray[1],lineArray[2]);
        var vectC = new THREE.Vector3(lineArray[3],lineArray[4],lineArray[5]);
        var globalPlane = new THREE.Plane().setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position,vectA,vectC);
        renderer.clippingPlanes = [ globalPlane ];
        myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) { removeClipping(); }, { once: true });
        myButton.innerText = 'Remove Slice';
        myButton.style.color = '#fc8c03';
        scene.remove(hitPlane);
        scene.remove(newLine);
    }, { once: true });
};

myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) { newClipping(); }, { once: true });
//working sample
```